# suspicious activity HTML error

Tags: registration

[image]When our members are trying to register with us they are presented with a HTML suspicious activity error.

Can anyone advise why?

I've searched through sites and all I can come up with is a IDS issue but i'm unsure how to turn this off.

Comment: Can you let us know what version of Civi, what CMS you're using and any more information about the error itself?

Comment: Hi Allen, its 4.7.6 with Joomla 3.5.1

Comment: Anymore help at all as we are still facing the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your CiviCRM logfile ([instructions to locate](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers#Debuggingfordevelopers-Logfiles)) should show details about the rejected form submissions.

Would be interested to hear details of what submitted data was triggering CiviCRM's IDS to reject registrations - if you can excerpt some details of a rejected submission from the logfile, someone might be able to give an informed reply to your question.

Comment: here's the log information but i really do not understand it:

Comment: Anymore help at all as we are still facing the issue?

Comment: Hi Mike - as above, if you provide some additional detail people can be of more assistance - looks like the actual detail was omitted? Try posting details from your CiviCRM log somewhere like https://gist.github.com, or try asking in the CiviCRM IRC channel.

Answer (score 1):

In your website's user permissions, you can give your members the "Skip IDS check" permission. I would caution you to not grant this to anonymous users.